# Heroku Deployment - Module Not Found - requireStack

Tags: node.js, heroku, mongoose

While deploying to Heroku, I am getting the following error:

```
2021-12-10T09:53:41.901516+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14) 
2021-12-10T09:53:41.901516+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
2021-12-10T09:53:41.901516+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
2021-12-10T09:53:41.901516+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12) {
2021-12-10T09:53:41.901517+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-12-10T09:53:41.901517+00:00 app[web.1]:   requireStack: [ '/app/middleware/authentication.js', '/app/app.js' ]
2021-12-10T09:53:41.901517+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-12-10T09:53:42.045642+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-12-10T09:53:42.100971+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-12-10T10:23:25.459845+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=kcjobs-api.herokuapp.com request_id=893141b7-de33-48ad-ac92-d6fdb099c93b fwd="203.91.225.88" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

My Github repo https://github.com/k4u5hik/node-express-course/tree/main/06-Practice
As you can see from the commit history that I have tried a few things but unsure how to resolve this.

If I happen to find a solution, i'll post it here. If anyone knows what's wrong, then a response would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: hi, were you able to solve this problem? i am also facing similar issue too

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it’s been a while since I resolved it however read the following:

I did manage to resolve it. The process is in the bit commit history comments. **Perhaps it was the node version number** that needed to match. Please also check the following commit notes.

I changed the node version from     "node": "14.x" to
"node": "16.x" in package.json

https://github.com/k4u5hik/node-express-course/commit/38f25d2f899eb3bb1f4776b0c27f918004c91070

**Next Commit**
I tested and the deployment worked!

https://github.com/k4u5hik/node-express-course/commit/43406aa04b0ee9da307159415c46d5e3ca478995

I also recall searching up **H10 error status 503** and **status 503 nodejs heroku** search results relating to Heroku

https://dev.to/lawrence_eagles/causes-of-heroku-h10-app-crashed-error-and-how-to-solve-them-3jnl

Hope it helps. Let us know.